# SQL get different random data every call

Tags: sql-server

need help for this, can SQL do this?

I have a table with 100 rows, I need to call 10 random rows from the table.
Can SQL make every query call give me different random data but not the chosen rows before

```
1st random query = get 10 random rows
2nd random query = get another 10 random rows different from the 1st call
.
.
.
10th random query = get the last 10 rows not chosen
```

I am still searching but no idea how, last option is every select do updates to the rows so not selected in next call

Comment: can you post the output

Comment: just like normal select output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 [your select list]
FROM [your table]
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Should give you 10 "random" rows per call.
If you need the rows to be 100% sure they're not selected previously - the only way to do it is to mark them so you can exclude them in where or remove them from table.

edit to expand on the mark approach:
*Pseudo code* for marking as extracted could look something like this:

```
DECLARE @tempList AS TABLE 

INSERT INTO @tempList
SELECT TOP 10 [your select list]
FROM [your table]
WHERE extracted = 0
ORDER BY NEWID()

UPDATE [your table]
SET extracted = 1
WHERE rows IN @tempList

SELECT * FROM @templist
```

Answer (score 0):

With this script, you just need to declare which run you are doing, it will always give the same rows for each run, you just have to change the value for @run. Result will seem random without actually being random:

```
DECLARE @run INT = 2

DECLARE @t table(id int)
INSERT @t 

SELECT x.id*10 + y.id + 1
FROM (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x(id)
CROSS JOIN
(values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) y(id)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT id, ntile(10) over (order by reverse(CHECKSUM(id, 'abc'))) rowgroup  FROM @t
)
SELECT id
FROM CTE
WHERE rowgroup = @run
```

Comment: that 10 means 10 data? if I have 100 data so I must create 100 values? hmm

Comment: no, your rows are already in the your table. This syntax just picks 10 values. You just need to replace @t with your table and id with your primary key column. If you had prepared better by including your table, I would have been able to post a better answer